# dropna() in Python

Tags: python, pandas

I encountered a code with a Function that takes a row of data,drops all missing values, and checks if all remaining values are greater than or equal to 0:

```
def check_null_or_valid(row_data):

    no_na = row_data.dropna()[1:-1]
    numeric = pd.to_numeric(no_na)
    ge0 = numeric >= 0
    return ge0
```

I didn't understand the significance of [1:-1] after dropna().Please help me with this.

Comment: You don't understand the `[1:-1]` or why is it used with `dropna()`?

Comment: I didn't understand why is it used here,it was needed to drop all the null values of a row, so why this slicing is implied.Here,last column of the row is also numeric and contains null values.

Answer (score 2):

The `[1:-1]` simply slices the array, selecting all elements except the first and last one.

```
import numpy as np
a = np.arange(5)   # a is now array([0, 1, 2, 3, 4])
b = a[1:-1]        # b is now array([1, 2, 3])
```

With a minus sign, you can access elements relative to the end of the array. `-1` is the last element, `-2` the second to last, et cetera.

Comment: Got it Bart,but still I am confused why is it used here along with dropna() when it was needed to drop all the null values of the row.                                               First column is a string here, so it's clear why it wasn't included but the last column is numeric only and contains null values.

Comment: Yes, without knowing the data or goal of the code, that is difficult to say.